# Better way to design payment database with multiple payment methods

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to make a payment/transaction database for a pretend online store (just trying to learn). 1 payment can purchase 1 to many items. 1 payment can only have 1 payment method.

To keep the example simple, there are 2 payment methods, PayPal and Bitcoin. Each payment method has different attributes, hence they must be different tables.

I have my payments table which tells me what transaction bought what item/s. However, you can see that if the `paypal_id`is NULL then the `bitcoin_id` column is not. This means there are a lot of NULL's which I think is not a good design. How can I have good design in a case like this?

---

paypal table

```
paypal_id | txn_id           | buyer_email    | amount
1         | 3sd7fgudf23sdf34 | john@mail.com  | 50.00
2         | 45shfik45345fg2s | mike@gmail.com | 100.00
```

---

bitcoin table

```
bitcoin_id | txn_id                     | amount
1          | 34327yhujndreygdiusfsdf324 | 0.19203
2          | sdfgurjibdsfhubhsdfinjo332 | 0.04123
```

---

items table

```
item_id | item name | price
1       | ball      | 50.00
2       | shirt     | 50.00
```

payments

```
payment_id | item_id | paypal_id | bitcoin_id
1          | 1       | 1         | NULL
2          | 1       | 2         | NULL
3          | 2       | 2         | NULL
4          | 1       | NULL      | 1
5          | 1       | NULL      | 1
6          | 1       | NULL      | 2
```

Comment: Yeah, you can create a `payment_type` table with column `payment_type_id`  and `payment_type_name` (Or any other names) for the current available paypal and bitcoin payment methods, and then reference to the `payment_type_id` field to the `payments` table

Comment: @AlonEitan If I did that, it would essentially do the same thing as the payments table though? Its just getting rid of the NULL's but adding more processing time to sql queries?

Comment: No, in the `payments` table you'll have `payment_type_id` (Referencing to the `payment_type` table) and `payemnt_id` - It will allow you to know the type of each payment and then get the payment details from the correct table

Comment: @AlonEitan I'm so confused. I can know the type of the payment already though. If `paypal_id` is `NULL` then the type is bitcoin. If the `bitcoin_id` is `NULL` then the type is PayPal. Unless I am not understanding what you are saying. The thing you are describing is still going to make me have at least one column (`paypal_id` or `bitcoin_id`) as NULL. One of the columns in the `payments` table will always be `NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design is fine.  But you might want to consider an alternative where you have a `payment_transactions` table and then related tables that use the same primary key:

```
create table payment_transactions (
    payments_transactions_id int auto_increment primary key,
    type varchar(255),
    payment_datetime datetime,  -- probably common to all payment methods
    . . . other columns if you like,
    unique (type, payments_transactions_id)  -- this will be used for foreign key references
);

create table bitcoin_payments (
    bitcoin_payments_transaction_id int primary key,
    type varchar(255) generated always as ('bitcoin'),
    . . . ,  -- columns specific to bitcoins
    foreign key (type, bitcoin_payments_transaction_id) references payments (type, payments_transactions_id)
);

-- similar for paypal
```

Then your payments table can have a foreign key to payments.

This handles much of the data modeling issue;

- You have proper declared foreign key relationships.
- Only one column is needed in `payments` regardless of the number of types.
- You can easily introduce new types.
- This guarantees one type per payment (via the inclusion of `type` in the foreign key reference).

One downside is that you need to insert each transaction twice.  First into the `payment_transactions` table and then into the proper table.

Payments are actually more complicated than you present.  A more realistic data model would handle:

- Transaction status.
- Retries.
- Partial payments.

Once you get the basic structure down, you might want to try adding in new capabilities.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your suggestion; It has directed me towards the right design. However, in this senerio, how do I query to select data from both payment transactions and the specific payments tables (bitcoin, paypal, etc.)

Comment: @DerickMarfo . . . If you have a question, you should ask it as a *question* not a comment.